# opts_knit$set(root.dir = ) working in knit but not chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a Rmd file saved in a folder one below my project([path]/scripts), and the data is in a parallel folder ([path]/data) and I can't seem to set the working directory and access the data when running the chunks. I use the setup chunk, as below, and then run code in a following chunk. If I knit the whole document it works fine but if I run the 2nd chunk on its own I get "Error: 'data/warriner_2013_emotional_valence.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('[path]/scripts')" Can anyone help out with what I'm doing wrong?

````
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    require("knitr")
    opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    opts_knit$set(root.dir = "..")
    ```

    ```{r}
    library(tidyverse)
    war <- read_csv('data/warriner_2013_emotional_valence.csv')
    ```
````

Other solutions I've found say to run the code in a separate chunk to the setup, which I'm doing.
I've also tried changing the R Markdown Global Options "Evaluate chunks in directory: 'Project'" - which has no effect.

```
    >sessionInfo()
    R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
    
    Matrix products: default
    
    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
    [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
    [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
    [5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
    [5] datasets  methods   base     
    
    other attached packages:
     [1] broom_0.7.0     forcats_0.5.0  
     [3] stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.1    
     [5] purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1    
     [7] tidyr_1.1.1     tibble_3.0.3   
     [9] ggplot2_3.3.2   tidyverse_1.3.0
    [11] knitr_1.29     
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       cellranger_1.1.0
     [3] pillar_1.4.6     compiler_4.0.2  
     [5] dbplyr_1.4.4     tools_4.0.2     
     [7] digest_0.6.25    lubridate_1.7.9 
     [9] jsonlite_1.7.0   evaluate_0.14   
    [11] lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0    
    [13] pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.7     
    [15] reprex_0.3.0     cli_2.0.2       
    [17] DBI_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.11 
    [19] yaml_2.2.1       haven_2.3.1     
    [21] xfun_0.16        withr_2.2.0     
    [23] xml2_1.3.2       httr_1.4.2      
    [25] fs_1.5.0         generics_0.0.2  
    [27] vctrs_0.3.2      hms_0.5.3       
    [29] grid_4.0.2       tidyselect_1.1.0
    [31] glue_1.4.1       R6_2.4.1        
    [33] fansi_0.4.1      readxl_1.3.1    
    [35] rmarkdown_2.3    modelr_0.1.8    
    [37] blob_1.2.1       magrittr_1.5    
    [39] backports_1.1.7  scales_1.1.1    
    [41] ellipsis_0.3.1   htmltools_0.5.0 
    [43] rvest_0.3.6      assertthat_0.2.1
    [45] colorspace_1.4-1 stringi_1.4.6   
    [47] munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Have you tried `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "../")`?

Comment: @Phil yes, no change. still thinks that it's working in the scripts directory.

Comment: If your create a chunk with the command `getwd()` what gets returned?

Comment: @Phil [path]/scripts if I manually run the chunks. If I knit, [path] - which is where I want it, so it definitely seems to be a knit vs run problem.

Comment: Hmm. Odd. There is this chapter that you may find useful https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html but I don't think it will resolve your problem. Another couple of solutions is to either post your problem at community.rstudio.com in the hopes someone there has found a solution, or maybe even filing an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown to see if Yihui has a suggestion. It might not be a proper usage of GH issues, but Yihui tends to be forgiving for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks @Phil I've asked in the rstudio community and if I don't get anywhere I'll add an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. What worked for me was not to use `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "../")`. Instead I set Tools -> Global Options -> Rmarkdown to `Project`.